# Checking for internet connection slows the load speed when disconnected

Tags: c#, .net

I want to create an easy autoupdate system in my program. It works fine, but I want it to proceed only when the user is connected to the internet.

I tried many ways, every worked, but when I'm disconnected from the internet, the time till the application loads is around 10 seconds, which is really slow. My program checks for the update on load and so does the connection test, which I think is the problem, because if I run the test inside a button click, it loads pretty fast, even when you are disconnected from the internet.

If you are curious, I tried to use every connection test I found, including `System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable();`.

Comment: So, what happens if you don't check first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that checking for a connection has a timeout.  When there's a connection it finds that out really fast (usually) and you don't notice the delay.  When you don't have a connection it has to do more checks and wait for responses.  I don't see anyway to adjust the timeout, and even if you could you'd risk it not detecting connections even if they were available.

You should run the check on a separate thread so that your GUI loading isn't disrupted.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was stuck at this point for 2 hours and it was so simple. I feel a bit dumb now..

Answer (score 1):

Rather than checking at startup, check on a background thread while the application is running and update then.  Any solution for checking connection can have a delay even if the internet is up, if there are DNS issues or just general slowness.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was stuck at this point for 2 hours and it was so simple. I feel a bit dumb now..